# Regex on quoted versus non quoted strings with the same content

Tags: javascript, php, html, regex

I am working on a web based text file editor.
It will be use to edit html, css, javascript and php scripts with and without
raw html.

In order to get raw html to display in a textarea field for editing, I have to escape closing textarea tags:
`<\/textarea>`.
This means that when php opens and reads the file to place in the host textarea tag set it does

```
str_replace('</text', '<\/text', $filestring);
```

So, when the file is edited and ready to be saved, I need to do replacement of the escape
(change `<\/text` back to `</text`)

But, there may be cases where there is a javascript string in a call to `document.write`, where the 
closing tags all need to remain escaped inside the string.

So I am trying to craft a regular expressing in javascript, and/or php that will detect cases of both
quoted and unquoted closing textarea tags.
Since the string will be multi line, I need to detect quote sets
that may straddle multiple lines.

so far:

```
    File: js/runner.js
    0   |/*
    1 |new file created by lab_0 script on Saturday 12th of April 2014 05:23:51 PM
    2 |*/
    3 |
    4 |function runner()
    5 |         {
    6 |          this.run = function()
    7 |               {
    8 |                var txt = '  "<\/textarEa>" kjhgy <\/teXtarea>   ';
    9 |                var pat = /.*[^'|"].*(<\/teXtarea>).*[^"|'].*/ig
    10|                var match = pat.exec(txt);
    11|                return 'match: '+match[1]+' -- '+txt.replace(match[1], '');
    12|               }
    13|         }
    14|
```

This will find and replace the X int teXtarea but if if do:

```
 var txt = '  "<\/textarEa>" kjhgy <\/teXtarea>  "<\/Textarea>" ';
```

it will match the last instance of `<\/Textarea>`. 
In addition, since the result of testing is written back to the browser, it appears to be removing
the escapes (\)

This is the code that writes the result of calls to Obj.runner.run;

```
case 'runner': // switch on e.target.id
   var ret = JSrun.run(); // runner instantiated as JSrun
   var put = document.getElementById('run');
   var res = document.createTextNode('JS Run result: '+ret);
   if(!put.hasChildNodes())
   {
       put.appendChild(res);
   }
   else
   {
       put.childNodes[0].data = 'JS Run result: '+ret;
   }
   break;
```

So the result is not visible in browser source to see if the escapes are still there.

Comment: Doing `str_replace` on parts of what you want to output as content inside the textarea is nonsense – using `htmlspecialchars` on it is the _correct_ thing to do.

Comment: I'd encode every instance of `<` as the html entity `&lt;`. By doing so, you'll get a very simple replacement rule that doesn't have any exceptions.

Comment: the file contents are being written to a textarea field. I don't want  html entities in it. I want to see and edit raw html markup